# It seems like ncurses is causing my loop to break early

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm running a program using ncurses with a loop that is supposed to generate a window for character movement, wait ~five seconds, clear the window, and start again. My thought is to have this be in a nested window that will do this ten times. However, after the first five seconds ends, the entire loop is broken and the program finishes.

```
int i=0;
while(i < 10)
{
   playwin.makeWindow();
   wtimeout(playwin.getWindow(), 0);

   originalTime = time(NULL);
   while(newTime < 5)
   {
      newTime = time(NULL);
      newTime -= originalTime;
      player.display();
      playwin.drawWindow();
      player.getMv();
   }
   wclear(playwin.getWindow());
   i++;
}
```

I expect that the window gets made, the wtimeout function will stop the getMv function from blocking, the nested while loop will display the window and allow the player to move around. After about five seconds, I expect that while loop to end, the window to get cleared, the iterator to increase, and for the loop to start again.

However, after the nested while loop ends, the iterator is already at 10 (verified with printf), so the whole loop breaks.

Comment: Where do you reset `newTime`?

Comment: where do you initialize newTime (before to do the very first `while(newTime < 5)`) ?

Comment: I know nothing about ncurses but what's the initial value of `newTime`? If it's 0, it'll never enter the loop.

Comment: newTime is initialized outside of the top loop as a time_t. My thought is that newTime and originalTime will be reset as the loop returns to that line.

Comment: @RobertKock Yes it will. 0 < 5. It should enter the loop.

Comment: @Chipster but only one time

Comment: @beatleboy07 you need to add a set/reset of _newTime_, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, after the nested while loop ends, the iterator is already at 10 (verified with printf), so the whole loop breaks.

there is no visible initialization of *newtime*, if its initial value (may be undefined if there is no init at all) is not less than 5 the `while(newTime < 5)...` is never executed because *newTime* never changes and *i* become quikly 10

If its initial value if less than 5 the `while(newTime < 5)...` is only executed one time because you do not reset its value after

Just add for instance `newTime = 0;` (or a value less than 5) before `while(newTime < 5) ...`

Comment: Yep! That was it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Before you enter the loop, `originalTime` is set to the current time.
As soon as you enter, `newTime` gets (probably) the same value.
You substract one from the other so `newTime` becomes 0.
It will therefore not enter the loop a second time.